# ROS in Docker: messaging with host PC

Tags: ros, communication, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I would like to know how to set up connection between ROS in Docker with ROS on host PC correctly.
Following some answers like these [[1]](https://answers.ros.org/question/318939/communication-between-docker-and-host/)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70466371/running-ros-in-docker-container-and-echo-pub-from-another-docker-container-withi) I can understand that connecting container to host network and exporting proper environmental variables should be enough.
However, when I try pub/echo between container and host PC, I get no response

Here is how I start everything:
On host PC I have the following in my .bashrc:

> ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.1
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.1:11311/
> ROS_IP=192.168.1.1

Then I start `roscore` in the first terminal. In the second terminal I run:
`docker run --net=host --name ros-test -it --rm osrf/ros:noetic-desktop`

And in the resulting second terminal I export the same environmental variables as shown above. Then I inspect available topics with `rostopic list` and can see default topics when roscore in running:

> /rosout
> /rosout_agg

Then in the third terminal from host PC I try simple publish command:
`rostopic pub -r 1 /test std_msgs/String "halo"`

Then try to receive messages in the container which is the second terminal: `rostopic echo /test`
I expect to receive messages, but there is nothing coming. When I do `rostopic hz /test`, it says "no new messages"
When I check `rostopic info /test` from fourth terminal I get the folllowing:

> Type: std_msgs/String
> Publishers:

- /rostopic_178825_1670943581897 (http://risc-SYS-5049A-TR:33815/)
  Subscribers:
- /rostopic_111_1670945011845 (http://docker-desktop:57739/)

With publisher being my third terminal and subscriber being my second terminal which is container

Is there something wrong with how I am doing things? Please advise or help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410484/ros-in-docker:-messaging-with-host-pc/) by [akim](https://answers.ros.org/users/55027/akim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-12-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I figured out it was my dumb mistake
I was following [these](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) instructions, but, apparently, I somehow skipped step (3) and didn't activate group changes. Now when I did, everything seems to work

---

Originally posted by [akim](https://answers.ros.org/users/55027/akim/) with karma: 11 on 2022-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0